# CSS Color Parsing Error

Tags: javafx-8, fxml

I get the error message:

```
Jun 25, 2014 11:39:18 AM com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser term
WARNING: CSS Error parsing '*{-fx-background-color:8ACC49;}: Unexpected token '8ACC' at [1,23]
```

I have an array of styles to set the background color:

```
private final String[] colors = new String[] { 
    "-fx-background-color:49CC49;",
    "-fx-background-color:5FCC49;",
    "-fx-background-color:8ACC49;", 
    "-fx-background-color:A0CC49;", 
    "-fx-background-color:CCCC49;", 
    "-fx-background-color:CCB649;", 
    "-fx-background-color:CC8A49;", 
    "-fx-background-color:CC7449;", 
    "-fx-background-color:CC4949;" };
```

Originally I just used the HEX values in the array, but the same error occurred as now. Populating the styles in the array was my second attempt to solve the problem. Also I had spaces around the colons, same error.

I used the following to set the style:

```
@FXML private Label lbl;

...

lbl.setStyle(color);
```

Only the first 3 colors give the error message.

Comment: Shouldn't the hex values be preceded by a `#`, as in `#49CC49`?

Comment: Yes in fact I just remembered it haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Missed # before the Color hex value . this code should be this:

```
private final String[] colors = new String[] { 
    "-fx-background-color:#49CC49;",
    "-fx-background-color:#5FCC49;",
    "-fx-background-color:#8ACC49;", 
    "-fx-background-color:#A0CC49;", 
    "-fx-background-color:#CCCC49;", 
    "-fx-background-color:#CCB649;", 
    "-fx-background-color:#CC8A49;", 
    "-fx-background-color:#CC7449;", 
    "-fx-background-color:#CC4949;" };
```

Comment: Aso if you have your value in format `0x49CC49` it will throw a related error too